# tweepy.error.TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 401

Tags: python, tweepy

I am using python 3.4.3 and  I followed all the instruction on the link:
http://www.lyonwj.com/2015/05/28/content-recommendation-from-links-shared-on-twitter/
i am getting error when i try running the code from the link

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = 'xxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxx'
access_token = 'xxx'
access_token_secret = 'xxx'
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit = True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify =         True)
ids = api.friends_ids()
urls = []

for friend in ids:
statuses = api.user_timeline(id=friend, count=200)
for status in statuses:
    if status.entities and status.entities['urls']:
        for url in status.entities['urls']:
            urls.append((url['expanded_url'], status.author.screen_name))
with open('urls.csv', 'w') as f:
for url in urls:
    f.write(url[0] + ',' + url[1] + '\n')
f.close()
```

---

### ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/file11.py", line 11, in <module>
    ids = api.friends_ids()
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 239, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 223, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 401
```

Comment: Error status 401 usually means not authorized (For whatever reason)

Comment: @AndréSchild But, i searched google on how to get authentication number for twitter api and in images i followed the steps mobile verification, and also i tried putting some link into urls[ ] acc. to https://twittercommunity.com/t/error-401-unauthorized/367/37 
do u know any other specific step that i could be missing

Comment: Double & Triple check the auth settings/numbers

Comment: been doing that for 3-4 hours now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

401 is the `Unauthorized` status code. It means that your credentials (in this case, your consumer/access tokens) are invalid. Try re-creating the credentials correctly again following the instructions [here.](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/application-owner-access-tokens)

Edit: If you're running *exactly* the code you posted, note that you must replace all the keys with the keys you generated using the above link.

EDIT:

As precised by LetsPlayYahtzee in comments below, it can also mean that you don't have access to the data you're requesting.

It can for instance happen when you're trying to retrieve tweets from a private user.

Comment: usually the `unauthorized` status code means that you don't have the right to retrieve data from a user because probably this user has set some kind of privacy rule on his/her profile on twitter

Answer (score 0):

When you copy and paste the keys/tokens to the python console, somehow a subtle character was inserted into the beginning and end of the keys. After two days I released this situation, I recreated all keys and tokens and paste them again to the python console.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30825592)